# Generating Complex Objects with Dynamic Properties Using Reflection Emit at Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection, reflection.emit

So The concept in my head kind of straightforward I'm just unsure how to implement this correctly.
I've got a class called `Banana` and a class Called `Dog` for simplicity sake.
Banana has a Dictionary of `<string,Banana>`
And Dog inherits from banana.

Now lets say i got another class lets call it `DynamicClass`.
this gets generated during runtime with reflection, some of its properties are simple like booleans etc and some are complex like Banana .

You can create a new dog class like this : `new Dog(Banana)`
Now what i need to do is Converts Banana to dog using reflection emit, so yeah i can check against the type of the propery and if its of type Banana i change the type lets say something like this:

```
`  public object TestMethod(object input)
    {
        Type inputType = input.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = inputType.GetProperties();

        AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName("DynamicAssembly");
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("DynamicModule");

        TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("DynamicType", TypeAttributes.Public);

        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            Type propType = prop.PropertyType;

            if (propType == typeof(Banana))
            {
                propType = typeof(Dog);
            }
         FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField("_" + prop.Name.ToLower(), propType,        FieldAttributes.Private);
            PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(prop.Name, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propType, null);`
```

Now the problem is I must also do this for the inner dictionary and recursively.
What i mean by that That i want to go over the inner properties of Banana and
find if one of them is of type `Dictionary<string,Banana>` and tell the `propType`  to now be equal to `Dictionary<string,Dog>`.

In addition i want to fill them with the fill them with the values from the previous Dictionary
Something in the form of `new Dog(Banana)` While looping over the KeyValuePair.
This also needs to happen recursively because those Bananas can contain more dictionaries, and in a different methode as to not overwrite the proprType and the propBuilder etc..  .
How can i implement this?

This is the full code if anybody cares to see:
[codeshare](https://codeshare.io/6pj1Yk)
(Gives me access is denied error)
This is a full example u can run this.

Tried Everything i had in mind before posting this
Another edit: link changed

Comment: Maybe you need AutoMapper?